# Create expand animation for default recyclerView (changing view's visibility from gone to visible)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, visibility

Do i necessairly need to change my recyclerView to expandableRecyclerView for doing animation of expand + animation of arrow drop down -> arrow up? Is there any way to implement simple slide down animation?

On button drop down arrow click i change visibility of textView and imageView from GONE to VISIBLE (also changing src of arrow button in code)

From:

[image: from]

To:

[image: to]

Here is some code just in case

```
taskViewHolder.showDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(taskViewHolder.description.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    taskViewHolder.showDesc.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.drop_up_arrow));
                    taskViewHolder.imgDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    taskViewHolder.description.setText(task.getDescription());
                    taskViewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    taskViewHolder.showDesc.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.drop_down_arrow));
                    taskViewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    taskViewHolder.imgDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look on my old project, I had to do something like you have told:

https://bitbucket.org/MauzerTheCat/music-example-app/src/master/